# Input value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a form with several dynamic input boxes. Some are denominators and some are nominators. I need to make sure a nominator is never greater than the denominator. I'm having issues collecting the value of textboxes. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<input id="ASTHMA_PTS_5-40_YEARS_OLD_(active_pts_only)_asthma" class="measureField denominator" type="text" size="5">    
<input id="Asthma_Pts_With_Symptoms_&_Control_Assessed_asthma" class="measureField " type="text"  size="5">
```

In the above case, the first box is the denominator.

I'm using this jQuery to grab the value of the fist field (class denominator) so I can compare to the value of the second field once I have it working

```
$(function(){
     $('#sd2').click(function(){ //sd2 is the id of the button to be clicked
        alert($('#ASTHMA_PTS_5-40_YEARS_OLD_(active_pts_only)_asthma').val());
    });
  });
```

I'm getting a blank alert when running this.

Thank you.

Comment: try giving the textbox an initial value text='test' and see if the alert is still blank

Comment: There's a value already which is being pulled from the database. Each textbox have a save link by its side. If I tie my jquery code around the save link for the first box it works. In this case I can't get the save link of the second textbox to read the value of the first textbox.

Comment: I'm suggesting that the jquery is reading the textbox before its value gets set.

Comment: I see what you're saying but that isn't it. Tried your idea but got a blank alert.

Comment: There must be something else interfering on your page. Tested your code in a Fiddle, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/s5je52og/ Also, remember to escape the meta characters `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^\`{|}~`. See: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thank you for replying. I came up with another solution. It's all done now. Thank you.